# Binarized bitmap not saving binarized in C#

Tags: c#, image-processing

**Scope:**

I am trying to "Binarize" ( convert to only two colors ) the images that can be found [here](http://www.fazenda.rj.gov.br/projetoCPS/codigoImagem). The binarized output must follow this logic : Characters will be painted as a "Color X" and everything else will be painted as "Color Y".

Ideally X is White and Y is black( but X and Y does not really matter).

**Observations:**

After some observations, i figured out that the characters are either "Yellow tones", "White Tones" or "Black Tones". 
Using the code Bellow, i should be able to recognize and convert all those "tones" (Color channels thresholding) to one color, and whole rest, into another color.

**Code Sample:**

```
// My Own Web Requests Class. You can use C# 
WebRequests wr = new WebRequests();  

Native One
Bitmap bmp;
string url = "http://www.fazenda.rj.gov.br/projetoCPS/codigoImagem";

bmp = wr.GetBitmap(url);
bmp.Save(@"captcha.bmp");

for (int i = 0; i < bmp.Width; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < bmp.Height; j++)
    {
        Color pixel = bmp.GetPixel(i, j);
        byte R, G, B;

        // Fetching RGB Values
        R = pixel.R;
        G = pixel.G;
        B = pixel.B;

        // Converting Black tones 
        if ((R < Color.Black.R + 110)
            && (G < Color.Black.G + 110)
            && (B < Color.Black.B + 110))
        {
            bmp.SetPixel(i, j, Color.Orange);
            continue;
        }

        // Converting Yellow tones
        if ((R > Color.Yellow.R - 110)
                && (G > Color.Yellow.G - 110)
                && (B < Color.Yellow.B + 110))
        {
            bmp.SetPixel(i, j, Color.Orange);
            continue;
        }

        // Converting White tones
        if ((R > Color.White.R - 110)
            && (G > Color.White.G - 110)
            && (B > Color.White.B - 110))
        {
            bmp.SetPixel(i, j, Color.Orange);
            continue;
        }

        bmp.SetPixel(i, j, Color.Orchid);
    }
}

bmp.Save(@"FilteredCaptcha.bmp");
```

**Problem:**

After running this code, the saved output (Bitmap) actually have more than the two colors i defined in code (which are "Orange" for characters and "Orchid" for everything else, in this sample).

Once i "Zoom In" using Windows Explorer / [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) / [ImageProcessingLab](http://www.aforgenet.com/projects/iplab/downloads.html) , there are "tones" of orange and "tones" of orchid.

**What am i missing here ? Why aren't the outputs binarized if the only uses "two" colors, instead of "tones" to Set the pixel Colors ?**

I uploaded some images to make your inspection job easier.

Input Bitmap:

[image: Input Bitmap]

Output Bitmap:

[image: Output Bitmap]

Comment: Can you upload the original `.bmp` or an uncompressed `.png`?  The image you uploaded is full of jpeg artifacts so it's impossible to tell anything.

Comment: @japreiss uploaded the original image.
What you mean by "uncompressed" ?

The webrequest gives me a "jpg" is this a problem that fact that i am saving it as a "bitmap" ?

Comment: Jpg file is compressed. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG

Comment: @AntonSizikov Russian Wikipedia : )
Thanks, im just kidding

Comment: Yep, fixed. first line from google is russian :)

Comment: Anything that is not a raw format will give you approximations.. and then more than 2 colours.

Comment: @BugFinder All right, but, how do i convert an image to a "raw" format ? Is there way i can "check" whether an image is "raw" or not by code ?

Comment: you are saving as a `.bmp` which is a raw format.  Probably imgur is converting it to a `.jpg` automatically.  Try saving as a `.png` instead and then uploading the `.png` directly to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change where you save it to:

```
bmp.Save(@"c:\temp\FilteredCaptcha.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Your code is clearly only setting two colours so the only possibility I see is that the source image is a JPG, and this format is being preseved when you save it.

Comment: Last Question, how are those images in "memory" ? They're binarized, right ? Only after the "JPEG" convertion they get messed up, correct ?

Comment: Yep! The framework holds off doing the JPG compression until you save.